# Como passar os dados recebidos de uma atividade e colocá-las em uma recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, serialização

Olá, sou iniciante em programação java e estou com dificuldades de passar algumas informações serializadas de  uma atividade para um recyclerview.

Quando a segunda atividade é iniciada não traz nenhuma informação. Antes de tentar colocar no recyclerview tentei usando Textview e deu certo, porém ao substituir para uma recycler não traz nenhuma informação. Acredito que seja simples, porém, como sou iniciante, estou sem ideia.

Abaixo segue o código do projeto.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

MainActivity

```
private void onOrderProduct() {
    bOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Cart cart = new Cart();
            cart.setComida(tvTitle.getText().toString());
            cart.setPreco(tvTotal.getText().toString());
            cart.setQuantidade(tvQtd.getText().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cart", cart);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView rvCart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

    rvCart = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tela5recycler_view);
    rvCart.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    rvCart.setLayoutManager(manager);


    if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cart") != null) {


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Cart cart = (Cart) intent.getSerializableExtra("cart");

        ArrayList<Cart> eList = new ArrayList<>() cart;
        Adapter adapter =new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), eList );
        rvCart.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ItemViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Cart> itemList;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cart> itemList){
    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.adapter_card, parent, false);

    ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
    return itemViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Cart item = itemList.get(position);

    holder.tvQtdcard.setText(item.getQuantidade());
    holder.tvComidacard.setText(item.getComida());
    holder.tvPrecocard.setText(item.getPreco());

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(itemList != null){
        return itemList.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView cvItem;
    public TextView tvQtdcard, tvComidacard, tvPrecocard;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cvItem = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tela1_1_1_1_1card);
        tvQtdcard = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tela5qtdcard);
        tvComidacard = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tela5comidacard);
        tvPrecocard = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tela5precocard);


    }
}
}
```

Cart.class Serializable

```
import java.io.Serializable;



public class Cart implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
private String comida;
private String quantidade;
private String preco;

public String getComida() {
    return comida;
}

public void setComida(String comida) {
    this.comida = comida;
}

public String getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(String quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

public String getPreco() {
    return preco;
}

public void setPreco(String preco) {
    this.preco = preco;
}

public String toString(){
    return comida;
}




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua RecyclerView espera um ArrayList e você está passando apenas um único item da primeira Activity para a segunda.

Se quiser mostrar apenas esse item, tem que modificar a inicialização do ArrayList da segunda Activity que está errada. Dessa forma, adicionando o único item no ArrayList que você definiu:

```
ArrayList<Cart> eList = new ArrayList<>();
eList.add(cart);
```

Comment: Cara, o procedimento deu certinho! Me ajudou pra caramba, vlw!